# error occur when I use getopt() to create options in c programming, can someone tell me where did i done wrong

Tags: c, getopt, getopts

here is my code down below, the code is incomplete, but the problem is I have set the t as the only option I have for this program, and when i run it with option -t input, it gives me error as following:
./run: invalid option -- 't'
Option error !

there is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#define DEFAULT_SECOND 10
extern int errno;
int errnum;



FILE* fin = NULL;


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int opt;
    int tFlag = FALSE;
    int defaultFlag = TRUE;
    int sec;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc,argv,"t:"))!=-1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 't':
                tFlag = TRUE;
                defaultFlag = FALSE;

                break;
            case '?':
                Printf("No such option, Now taking Exit...");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - optind; ++i)
    {
        fin = fopen(argv[optind + i], "r");
        if (fin == NULL)
        {
            errnum = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errnum));
            exit(1);
        }
        if (defaultFlag == TRUE)
        {
            sec = defaultFlag;
        }
        if (tFlag == TRUE)
        {
            if((sec = atoi(optarg)==-1))
            {
                printf("input error!!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

please tell me if I have wrongfully set the option for -t, if possible please tell me where is the problem.

Comment: How do you invoke (run) your program? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the exact command line, in full and complete, you use when running the program.

Comment: On another note: Never do `extern int errno;` It might actually be wrong.